# HighPoint RAID Controller can't see drives

Tags: raid

I've just built a system with a HighPoint 2720 RAID controller. Everything appears to be OK, except that the controller doesn't see any of my drives - the RAID BIOS displays "ERROR. No Suitable disks". I have tried a WD SATA, Seagate SATA, and OCZ Vertex 3 SATA. I am using MiniSAS to 4x SATA breakout cables.

How do I get this working? I've tried to sign up for HighPoint support, but their support site doesn't appear to be functioning correctly.

**UPDATE**: SOLVED - Vendor supplied us with Reverse Breakout cables instead of the Forward Breakout cables that we ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the raid controller to pass throught mode and do software raid. It is not worth the trouble if it does not work out-of-the-box. Of course this onlu works with linux. I just realized you did not tell what kind of OS do you use.

Comment: This is a Windows system, so unfortunately it doesn't sound like this solution will help.